# Single definition of value used multiple times in log4cxx configuration

Tags: xml, dtd, log4cxx

I have a log4cxx.xml configuration file which defines multiple rolling file appenders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
  <appender name="A" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="file1.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="12MB" />
    ...
  </appender>
  ...
  <appender name="G" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="file7.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="12MB" />
    ...
  </appender>
  <!-- Loggers referencing A, B, ..., G -->
```

I would like to have one place, in the file, where I define the maximum file size.  I know that I can replace 12MB with ${MAX_FILE_SIZE} and get the value from the environment, but I do not want to have to set an environment variable.

It seemed that the following should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration  [
<!ENTITY maxFileSize "12MB">
]>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
  <appender name="A" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="file1.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="&maxFileSize" />
    ...
  </appender>
  ...
```

However, this fails with `log4cxx: Error parsing file [log4cxx.xml], Internal errorXML parser error code: not well-formed (invalid token) (4)`.

My guess as to what is going wrong is that either I got the DOCTYPE statement wrong, or log4cxx does not have a full XML parser and does not expect the DOCTYPE.  I have little experience with DTDs, so both answers are plausible to me.

Is there a way to fix the DOCTYPE to make this work, or a completely different method that will get my desired result of specifying the maximum file size at one location in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just missed the semicolon in the entity reference.

It should look like this:

```
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="&maxFileSize;" />
```

The doctype declaration looks fine.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks!